# Create3 deployment with proxy contract ownership?

Tags: hardhat, openzeppelin-contracts, proxy-contracts, create2

I have deployed an upgradable proxy contract with create3factory from solmate.
In my contract i transfer ownership to an address. But still the owner ship is not on that address. Its a differant address. Here is my contract how should i do?
Here is box contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Box is Initializable, OwnableUpgradeable {
    uint256 public value;

    function initialize(uint256 _value, address _owner) public initializer {
        __Ownable_init();
        transferOwnership(_owner);
        value = _value;
        console.log(_owner);
    }

    /// @custom:oz-upgrades-unsafe-allow constructor
    constructor() {
        _disableInitializers();
    }

    // Emitted when the stored value changes
    event ValueChanged(uint256 newValue);

    // Stores a new value in the contract
    function store(uint256 newValue) public onlyOwner {
        value = newValue;
        emit ValueChanged(newValue);
    }

    // Reads the last stored value
    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Here is create3 contract:

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "solmate/src/utils/CREATE3.sol";

contract Create3Factory is Ownable {
    event Deployed(address contractAddress);

    function deploy(
        bytes32 _salt,
        bytes memory _creationCode
    ) external payable onlyOwner returns (address deployed) {
        bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, _salt));
        deployed = CREATE3.deploy(salt, _creationCode, msg.value);
        emit Deployed(deployed);
    }

    function getDeployedAddress(
        address _deployer,
        bytes32 _salt
    ) external view returns (address) {
        bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_deployer, _salt));
        return CREATE3.getDeployed(salt);
    }
}
```

Deployment scripts:

```
    module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
  const { deploy, log } = deployments;
  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();
  const args = [];

  const Box = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Box");
  const Create3Factory = await hre.deployments.get("Create3Factory");
  const create3Factory = await hre.ethers.getContractAt(
    "Create3Factory",
    Create3Factory.address
  );

  const ProxyAdmin = await hre.deployments.get("ProxyAdmin");
  const proxyAdmin = await hre.ethers.getContractAt(
    "ProxyAdmin",
    ProxyAdmin.address
  );

  const box = await Box.deploy();
  await box.deployed();
  console.log("box address: ", box.address);

  const functionData = box.interface.encodeFunctionData("initialize", [
    42,
    deployer,
  ]);

  const TransparentProxyCreationCode = await getCreationCode({
    contractName: "TransparentProxy",
    constructorArgs: {
      types: ["address", "address", "bytes"],
      values: [box.address, proxyAdmin.address, functionData],
    },
  });

  const tx2 = await create3Factory.deploy(
    "0x43f379c0214535bb128fca03870dd998b303c983a3d40d49c0ab85fc3f8c0f1f",
    TransparentProxyCreationCode
  );
  const receipt = await tx2.wait();
  const parsedEvents = receipt.events?.map((event) => {
    return {
      name: event.event,
      args: event.args,
    };
  });

  if (!parsedEvents) {
    throw new Error("No events found");
  }

  const { contractAddress } = parsedEvents.find(
    (event) => event.name === "Deployed"
  )?.args;

  console.log("proxyAddress: ", contractAddress);
};
const getCreationCode = async ({ contractName, constructorArgs }) => {
  const bytecode = (await ethers.getContractFactory(contractName)).bytecode;

  return `${bytecode}${ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder
    .encode(constructorArgs.types, constructorArgs.values)
    .slice(2)}`;
};

module.exports.tags = ["all", "proxy"];
```

Here is i am try to check owner of the contract:

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const [deployer, user, user1] = await ethers.getSigners();

  console.log(user.address);

  const Box = await ethers.getContractFactory("Box");
  const box = Box.attach("PUT ADDRESS OF THE ADDRESS OF CONTRACT ADDRESS FROM DEPLOYMENT SCRIPT ");

  console.log(await box.owner());


}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Here is result of console.log this script 0xE20420d16367dCbB69Be37f57F76cCe594b6C35C
this is not the deployer address. The deployer address is 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266 which is first address of hardhat node.